# Spring boot ver 3.0.5 postgresql JPA query failure

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Upgraded Spring boot version 2.7.2 to 3.0.5 and jdk 11 to 17. with this the JPARepository queries are failing. Using PostgreSql DB.

Are Joins supported??

Below is the query:

```
@Query(value = "select ls.col1 from Sttaus ls right join ls.col2 al on ls.col2= al.id " +
            "where ls.status is null and al.Key = Key " +
            "order by al.lastUpdatedAt")
    Slice<Sttaus > getDetails(@Param(Key") String Key, Pageable pageable);
```

Exceptions are :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicAttributeMapping cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EntityValuedModelPart (org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicAttributeMapping and org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EntityValuedModelPart are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitTableGroup(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:3505)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQualifiedAttributeJoin(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:3440)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQualifiedAttributeJoin(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:416)
```

Comment: We had the same exception in a slightly different context during a SpringBoot upgrade from 2 to 3. We used the CriteriaBuilder to build a selection returning queryRoot.in(subquery) where queryRoot was a Root<SomeEntity> but subquery was a query returning ids only. We changed it to queryRoot.get("id").in(subquery) and it worked as before. So maybe your query might be missing an access to an id field like ls.col2.id=...? It's just a guess but maybe worth a try. It would be nice to know whether/how you solved it.

Comment: @alf42red your solution is working for my similar problem. I did something like this query simplified: `select p from Person p where p in (select p2.id from Person p2 where p2.name = 'Whatever'`. The solution was to change `p in (select` to `p.id in (select`.